# Extract a substring new column based on a substring based on conditions ideally with Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, for-loop

I got a data set (Excel) with hundreds of entries. In one string column there is most of the information. The information is divided by '_' and typed in by humans. Therefore, it is not possible to work with index positions.

To create a usable data basis it's mandatory to extract information from this column in another column.

The search pattern = '**v**' is alone not enough. But combined with the condition that the first item has to be a digit it works.

I tried to get it to work with iterrows, iteritems, str.strip, str.extract and many more. But the best solution I received with a for-loop.

```
     pattern = '_*v*_'
    test = []


    for i in df['col']:
'#Split the string in substrings
        i = i.split('_')
        for c in i:
            if c.find('x') == 1:
                if c[0].isdigit():
                   # print(c)
                    test.append(c)
                else:
'#To be able to fix a few rows manually
                    test.append(0)
[4]: test =[22v3, 33v55, 4v2]



#Input

+-----------+-----------+
|    col    | targetcol |
+-----------+-----------+
| as_22v3   |           |
| 33v55_bdd |           |
| Ave_4v2   |           |
+-----------+-----------+

#Output

+-----------+-----------+--+
|    col    | targetcol |  |
+-----------+-----------+--+
| as_22v3   | 22v3      |  |
| 33v55_bdd | 33v55     |  |
| Ave_4v2   | 4v2       |  |
+-----------+-----------+--+
```

My code does work, but only for the first few rows. It stops after 36 values and I can't figure out why. There is no error message besides of course that it is not possible to assign the list to a DataFrame series since it has not the same size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`pandas.Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) should help:

```py
>>> df['col'].str.extract(r'(\d+v+\d+)')
       0
0   22v3
1  33v55
2    4v2
```

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col': ['as_22v3', '33v55_bdd', 'Ave_4v2']
})
df['targetcol'] = df['col'].str.extract(r'(\d+v+\d+)')
```

---

## EDIT

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col': ['as_22v3', '33v55_bdd', 'Ave_4v2', '_22 v3', 'space 2,2v3', '2.v3',
    '2.111v999', 'asd.123v77', '1    v7', '123 v 8135']
})

pattern = r'(\d+(\,[0-9]+)?(\s+)?v\d+)'

df['result'] = df['col'].str.extract(pattern)[0]
```

```py
           col   result
0      as_22v3     22v3
1    33v55_bdd    33v55
2      Ave_4v2      4v2
3       _22 v3    22 v3
4  space 2,2v3    2,2v3
5         2.v3      NaN
6    2.111v999  111v999
7   asd.123v77   123v77
8      1    v7  1    v7
9   123 v 8135      NaN
```

Comment: Wow, thank you!. Thats a lot easier. Regex is really hard for me to understand.

By doing this I regognized for some values it doesn't work because they have whitespace beetween the v and the digit(s). 
Also there are others which have a decimal comma. 
So the Input can also be like as "_22 v3" and as " 2,2v3" I tried to modify the pattern and came up with this: 
(r'(\d+[.,]??x+\d+)')

But it doesn't work either. Is there a good ressource to learn more about regex?

Comment: @heathaze92 I edited my answer. Now it should capture spaces and commas

Comment: @heathaze92 I'm not quite there with regex myself, but I always use this [site](https://regex101.com/) to try find the correct pattern. if you have any questions about regex, `regex` tag should help

Answer (score 0):

You say it stops after 36 values? You say it is Excel file you are processing? One thing you could try is to save data set to .csv file and try to read this file in with pd.read_csv function. There are sometimes some extra characters in Excel file that are not easily visible.